# How are polymerDart components deployed in Dartium versus their Source tree

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, dart-polymer

When i am making PolymerElements in Dart and have folders organized to store css/html/dart files, when i run index.html in Dartium and look at the sources it seems that everything is shifted around and stored in the `packages` folder.

Im trying to find these custom PolymerElement dart files I have written, but to no avail.  It seems when looking at index.html at runtime, it will paste the css/html as required into the custom elements i had created,  but im still not sure where the dart files themselves are stored.

Right now I have a SRC structure that looks like:

```
.pub/
lib/
  common/
  ...
  tw_datagrid/
    a.css
    a.html
    a.dart
packages/
web/
  packages/
  index.html
  main.dart
```

and for the deployment to Index, i look at the source and see the following:

```
proj_name/web
  packages/
```

it seems that packages in the web sources has a more robust set of information.  My logic tends to lean towards it containing the imported libraries as well.

Still though, i cant find the new location of:  `a.dart` within the `packages/` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html, CSS and JS is inlined into `index.html`. For CSS files this can be disabled.
Source files from the library directory can be found in Dartium (in the `Sources` tab in the dev-tools) under the `(no domain)` node under `package:proj_name/tw_datagrid/a.dart`